# Receive feedback during a command execution using Apache Exec

Tags: java, apache, exec

I've implemented an example from Apaches's web: http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html

What I need now is listen / receive feedback from a heavy process.

I know how to print the process result using  setStreamHandler method but this result is displayed once the execution finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read `PumpStreamHandler` and `InputStreamPumper`. You basically want almost exactly these classes. Just modify the `InputStreamPumper.run()` loop. Instead of `os.write()`, it should fire your event. To allow the results to start arriving while your process is running, call it as follows:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine(yourExecutable);
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();

Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setStreamHandler(new YourPumpStreamHandler());
executor.execute(cmdLine, resultHandler);
// until waitFor returns, the process is running and events can be generated
int exitValue = resultHandler.waitFor();
```